# android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" with keyboard use

Tags: android

I have a button bar (its parent is a RelativeLayout of the total screen) on the bottom of screen (with the help of android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true")

The thing is, when the keyboard is shown, this bar appeared just above the keyboard, which reduces the size of the rest of the display.

Have you any idea on how to force the button bar to stay on the bottom of the screen even when the keyboard is shown?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity.
See [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more details.

Comment: I will, not available now ;)

Comment: @deville any idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956157/selectionbar-is-hidden