# Selectionbar is hidden

Tags: android, android-actionbar, adjustpan

I have added **`adjustPan`** in `Manifest.xml` file here is my `Activity` tag in `Manifest.xml`

```
android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Problem is this when I added **`adjustPan`** my Selection bar(CAB) is hidden. When I remove **`adjustPan`** from `Manifest.xml` Its showing perfect. Let me know what's wrong with  **adjustPan**?[image: Selectionbar]